# Exit not getting executed in the script

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

```
date
ls
exit
```

On executing this script, the commands `date` and `ls` are executed but the terminal doesn't close. Why?

Comment: because the script runs in its own sub-shell. you exited THAT sub-shell, not the parent shell that ran the script.

Comment: Try `. ./abc` instead, if you really want it to exit your terminal for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script will exit only the shell it's running in. When you do `./abc` then parent shell forks and execs a subshell in which `./abc` is run.
Just to be bit more obvious about *subshell* exit, consider the following example:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo hi
(exit)
echo hello
```

prints both `hi` and `hello`. The `exit` happens in the subshell. So, the script won't exit and hence the last `echo hello` gets executed.

To see that the script itself exits, try

```
#!/bin/bash

echo hi
exit
echo hello
```

Running this script will output just "hi"; the exit command terminates the script (but not the shell running in your terminal) before it reaches `echo hello`.

Comment: Helpful, but note that  a (non-sourced) script is _not_ a _subshell_, but _a child process that happens to run another shell instance_ (the specific shell / executable is determined by the script's shebang line or absence thereof, and may be a different shell altogether).
This distinction is important, because a true subshell (as in your `(exit)` example) has a copy of the current shell's environment (inherits all variables, aliases, functions, ...), which is not true of a shell instance used to run a script.